# Character Justification Across Image Using PHP GD

Tags: php, image, imagemagick, gd

I'm trying to create dynamic images that have a text string with spaces that are justified across the image.

[image]

I've discovered code that purports to justify a word string across an image and appears to work.  Here's my current code attempt. It 'works' in the sense that it generates the image with font but doesn't justify across the entire width currently set at "564".

I assume that I need to take my character count multiply by the width based upon font face and font size and then divide that by the image width to get the character spacing. This goes beyond my coding abilities so I was hoping for some insight and direction.

```
    <?php
$font = "";
$image = ImageCreateFromPNG( "");
//$image = ImageCreateFromJPEG( "sample.jpg" );
//$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$text = $_REQUEST["month"];
$angle ="0";
$left ="10";
$top ="15";
$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 247,149,22);
$max_width="564";
$minspacing="3";
$linespacing ="1";
$size="24";
$a = imagettftextjustified($image, $size, $angle, $left, $top , $color, $font, $text, $max_width, $minspacing,$linespacing=1);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagejpeg($image,NULL,100);

function imagettftextjustified(&$image, $size, $angle, $left, $top, $color, $font, $text, $max_width, $minspacing=3,$linespacing=1)
{
$wordwidth = array();
$linewidth = array();
$linewordcount = array();
$largest_line_height = 0;
$lineno=0;
//words
////$words=explode(" ",$text);
//characters
$words=str_split($text);
$wordcount = count_chars( $text);
$wln=0;
$linewidth[$lineno]=0;
$linewordcount[$lineno]=0;
foreach ($words as $word)
{
$dimensions = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $word);
$line_width = $dimensions[2] - $dimensions[0];
$line_height = $dimensions[1] - $dimensions[7];
if ($line_height>$largest_line_height) $largest_line_height=$line_height;
if (($linewidth[$lineno]+$line_width+$minspacing)>$max_width)
{
$lineno++;
$linewidth[$lineno]=0;
$linewordcount[$lineno]=0;
$wln=0;
}
$linewidth[$lineno]+=$line_width+$minspacing;
$wordwidth[$lineno][$wln]=$line_width;
$wordtext[$lineno][$wln]=$word;
$linewordcount[$lineno]++;
$wln++;
}
for ($ln=0;$ln<=$lineno;$ln++)
{
$slack=$max_width-$linewidth[$ln];
if (($linewordcount[$ln]>1)&&($ln!=$lineno)) $spacing=($slack/($linewordcount[$ln]-1));
else $spacing=$minspacing;
$x=0;
for ($w=0;$w<$linewordcount[$ln];$w++)
{
imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $left + intval($x), $top + $largest_line_height + ($largest_line_height * $ln * $linespacing), $color, $font, $wordtext[$ln][$w]);
$x+=$wordwidth[$ln][$w]+$spacing+$minspacing;
}
}
return true;
}
?>
```